# How can I hide a link using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, show-hide

I've used jQuery to hide a link on a webpage, but it can be easily revealed by viewing the source. I want to avoid loading the link upon page load, and then load it using AJAX or something similar by default, when the user has clicked a button to see the link.

The web page should fetch the hidden url only after user clicks the button.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Have you read just anything about ajax?

Comment: Agreed this is more complex than a simple answer.  Don't render the item initially and just JQuery ajax to retrieve the html from the server.  Look at jquery.ajax.  It's not that hard, but I don't need to repeat their documentation.

Comment: Better solution is to just have the user click the button which simply hits a script on your server which does a redirect to whatever the url should be. Once that's done, you can't hide the url anymore, but at least they can't see it in the browser until they actually click the button.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: @cyber criminal - not "being good at ajax" is no big deal in this case since the jquery library handles everything for you. It is as simple as setting a click listener, defining the target url on click, echoing the link as a result and placing the data in the dom where you want. Every single bit of that is given in example all over the internet. just look up $.ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are asking is for a way to simply deliver the page without the link in the source, and then have the link be loaded through Ajax when needed.

It is important to read the jQuery documentation, to fully understand the possibilities offered by jQuery Ajax.

- [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

  - a wrapper for jQuery Ajax to load HTML
- [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**Update:**
A full single file example, name it 'ajax_link.php':

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['link'])) : ?>
<a href="yourlink.html">the link</a>
<?php else: ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#clicktoload').click(function () {
                    $('#wheretoshowlink').load('ajax_link.php?link=true');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <title>Ajax load link example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wheretoshowlink"></div>
        <button id="clicktoload">your button</button>
    </body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to completely hide a link on a webpage.
Even if you bring the link in through javascript, a visitor could still see it in a number of different DOM tools built-in and otherwise.

If you want a URL to be visible after a button click, attach an AJAX event to the button so it will pull it in when the button is clicked.

See jQuery AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Let me read the documentation.

Comment: if you inspect the js, the link could still be viewed

Comment: -1 I don't believe you fully understand what Cyber Criminal was asking, although it is true that he should have tried the documentation before asking.

Comment: Yea, that's why I want to use AJAX. Whenever user clicks the button, AJAX should fetch the PHP file from the server and displays it. I'm not good at AJAX.

Comment: @andrewjackson, Did you understand what he was asking? It's exactly what he's looking for, AJAX to pull in the URL, which is why I linked to the AJAX documentation.

Comment: Sorry maybe you did, however "It's not possible to completely..." seemed to imply that you didn't.